# listdir() No such file or directory

Tags: python

I have a problem with listdir(). I'm trying to change format of jpg files listed in a dir and i have this traceback.
Here my code :

```
import face_recognition
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

path = "./unknown_faces"

for f in os.listdir(path):
    print (f)
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(f)
        fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
        i.save('png/{}.png'.format(fn))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exemple_face.py", line 11, in <module>
    i = Image.open(f)
  File "/home/jonas/.pyenv/versions/facereco/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yo.jpg'
```

[Here my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOHTl.png)

Thanks

Comment: You are opening the `filename` append path to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to open 'yo.jpg' in your root directory but you get your filenames from the 'path' directory.
Try to change line 11 to:

```
i = Image.open(path + f)
```

Comment: `path + f` - better is `os.path.join(path,f)`

Comment: Why would you use 'join' instead of '+'? I'm not sure, but I think I read about some experiments where '+' was much faster than 'join'. Of course this runtime improvement is probably not significant in this case

Comment: The main reason is that the results of `os.path.join(path,f)` and `path + f` are different :-) note that it is not "normal" string join, but `os.path` join, adding "path delimiter" between the arguments (`/` for linux for example)

Answer (score 5):

the file name from os.listdir is relative to ./unknown_faces, so you need to join the folder and file names:

```py
fpath = os.path.join(path, f)
i = Image.open(fpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
path = "./unknown_faces"

for f in os.listdir(path):
    print (f)
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open("{}/{}".format(path, f))
        fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
        i.save('png/{}.png'.format(fn))
```

Your `.jpg` file can't be found because of the wrong path. You need to add path of the file when opening (`Image.open("{}/{}".format(path, f))`).

Comment: `{}/{}".format(path, f)` - would it work on Windows? `os.path.join(path,f)` is here for these cases

Comment: Ok, nice, didn't know it. Still **I personally** would use `os.path.join(path,f)` as a more semantic variant

Comment: Great, Nice choice!